# jquery get elements by class name

Tags: html, arrays, parsing, getelementsbyclassname

I'm using Jquery to get a list of elements having a class "x".

html:

```
<p class="x">Some content</p>
<p class="x">Some content#2</p>
```

If we use Jquery to get both these html elements and do something with it- we use something like:

$(".x").text("changed text");

This will change the text of both the paragraphs. From $(".x") - How can we add a array - subscript notation like we can do with getElementsByclassName as follows:

document.getElementsByClassName("x")[0].innerHTML

I tried this
$(".x")[0].text("asasa")- it doesn't work gives a typeerror in javascript console. I also tried get API here -http://jsfiddle.net/probosckie/jnz825mp/ - and it doesnt work

**the error is Uncaught TypeError: $(...).get(...).text is not a function
None of the solutions below WORK!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this way:

```
$('.x:eq(0)').text('changed text');
```

or:

```
$('.x').eq(1).text('bbb');
```

both works well

sorry for my before answer..

Comment: this is not working. i tried it in chrome and it's giving an error in Console.

Comment: @Prabhas you can try this

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `get()` method for accessing an element from the array, for example:

```
$(".x").get(index).textContent = "changed text";
```

More info: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

And for obtaining HTML (`innerHTML`) you call the `.html()` function:

```
// This is equal to document.getElementsByClassName("x")[0].innerHTML
$(".x").get(0).innerHTML;
```

If you want to set the HTML, then just provide your HTML code inside the function call like this `.html('<h1>Hello, World!</h1>')`.

**EDIT**: `.get()` returns the DOM object not the jQuery wrapped element. Therefore `.text()` and `.html()` doesn't work. Unless you wrap it.

More options:

```
$(".x").get(0).innerHTML;
$($(".x").get(0)).html();
$(".x:first").html();
```

Comment: You realize that if you have 1000 `.x` it will fill 1000 items in the jQuery object (before filtered)

Comment: That is true. In that case it is best to optimize it with another approach. Maybe with `document.querySelector('.x')`, which returns only one element (the first one). You can also wrap it in jQuery if you wish.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).get(...).text is not a function

Comment: I have made an edit. `.get()` does not return a jQuery element, but the plain DOM element. Therefore you cannot call jQuery specific functions on it.

Comment: Great. thanks. Got it. any idea how to get a specific element from the jquery array??

Comment: Specific in what way? By index or other criteria?

Answer (score 0):

The solution `$(".x").get(index)...` will first match *all* `.x` (which is bad performance). And *then* it will filter

If you have 1000 `.x` it will fill an 1000 items in the jQuery object (before filtered)

But

`$(".x:first").text("changed text");` will do better because it won't yield all `.x` and then filter  , but will do it at a first single step (without  filling 1000 items)